# Image in not displaying is laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

everybody please help me image that have uploaded is not showing in blade.

code of product controller is given below

```php
 if($request->hasFile("attr_image.$key")){
                if($paidArr[$key]!=''){ 
                    $arrImage=DB::table('products_attr')->where(['id'=>$paidArr[$key]])->get();
                    if(Storage::exists('/public/media/'.$arrImage[0]->attr_image)){
                        Storage::delete('/public/media/'.$arrImage[0]->attr_image);
                    }
                }

                $rand=rand('111111111','999999999');
                $attr_image=$request->file("attr_image.$key");
                $ext=$attr_image->extension();
                $image_name=$rand.'.'.$ext;
                $request->file("attr_image.$key")->storeAs('/public/media',$image_name);
                $productAttrArr['attr_image']=$image_name;
            }
```

and code product that blade where image is not showing is

```php
 @if($list->image!='')
  <img width="100px" src="{{asset('storage/media/'.$list->image)}}"/>
 @endif
```

while inspecting is found this url

```php
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/media/1631177564.jpg"
```

here  is screen shot from problem

[image]

Comment: Use `{{ dd($list->image) }}` to see what it contains. Does the image exist? Any "suspicious" characters in the name? Or inspect the element in your browser

Comment: Unrelated fyi, the `width` attribute doesn't take a unit, it's integer only

Comment: When you open this url in your browser **http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/media/1631177564.jpg** Is the image displayed?

Comment: Did you ran `php artisan storage:link` to create symbolic link?

Comment: Autista_z yes but not woking

Comment: Autista_Z  no there is no image there when i open this url in browser